# Testing an array is empty in a if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

i used this way to testing an array $arr if empty

```
if(!empty($arr)){ //do something }
```

recently, i saw someone use an another like:

```
if($arr){ //do something }
```

just want to know is't the second way a simply way to testing an array or is there some potential risk here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty array like `array()` is regarded as equal to `false`. So a simple `if ($arr)` works perfectly fine.

`empty` does the same kind of comparison, but does not trigger a `NOTICE` about missing variables, should the variable `$arr` not exist at all. You should not use `empty` if you are sure the variable exists, since it suppresses valuable error reporting. Only use `empty` if you really don't know whether a variable exists or not and have no control over it.

For more information about `empty` see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 3):

The second casts the array to a boolean. Empty arrays are cast to `false`, anything else to `true`. So `if($arr)` and `if(!empty($arr))` are functionally identical.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are functionally equivalent. The documentation for [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) mentions the following things are considered to be empty

```
"", 0, 0.0, "0", NULL, FALSE, array(), var $var;
```

Taking a look at [casting to a bool](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), we can see that the list matches the list, which means both methods handle different types in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The second way is not ideal. If you use the second method and determine you're dealing with an array (and you aren't) and pass it to a foreach statement, you'll end up with an error. It is also more instructive for what you're checking to do more than test with if($arr).

My preference is:

```
if (is_array($arr) && count($arr) > 0) {
    //work with array
}
```

Edit: I think my underlying point here is that the ability to test an array's existence is only part of the problem. If $arr turns out to be a string, a more robust check is needed.

Comment: `!empty($arr)` will also return true if `$arr` is not an array (for instance an integer `1`)

Comment: Indeed, not empty is not ideal either. +1